# On the identity $\vec\tau_{net}=\overleftrightarrow I_{C} \vec \alpha + \vec \omega \times (\overleftrightarrow I_{C} \vec \omega)$

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

**Part 1**

I recently came across the following identity

$$\vec\tau_{net}=\overleftrightarrow I_{C}\vec \alpha + \vec \omega \times (\overleftrightarrow I_{C} \vec \omega)$$

which gives the $\vec\tau_{net}$ of a rigid body irrespective of whether the center of mass is in motion or in rest ($\overleftrightarrow I_{C}$ is the inertia tensor of the body with respect to the center of mass).

*Question 1*

What are the conditions required for the rigid body so that this expression reduces to:

$$\vec\tau_{net}=I_{C}\vec\alpha$$

where $I_{C}$ is the scalar inertia?

**Part 2**

The derivation for the general formula for $\vec\tau_{net}$ used:

$$\vec\tau_{net}=\sum_{i}m_{i}[(\vec r_{i}-\vec r_{C})\times \vec a_{i}]$$

and it hinged on the fact:

$$\vec a_{i}=\vec \alpha \times (\vec r_{i}-\vec r_{C})+\vec \omega \times [\vec \omega \times (\vec r_{i}-\vec r_{C})]+\vec a_{C}$$

(See this Wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Resultant_torque) for reference.)

*Question 2*

The formula for $\vec a_{i}$ implies that if you were to move with the center of mass, you would see the particles of the rigid body revolving about the center of mass. How is this justified?

**Note**

If you could show some math in your response or provide some useful resources, it would be appreciated. Please point out any step in my working which is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Part 1

The second part of  $\boldsymbol{\tau}_C = {\rm I}_C\;\boldsymbol{\alpha}+\boldsymbol{\omega}\times {\rm I}_C\boldsymbol{\omega}$ is zero when ${\rm I}_C\boldsymbol{\omega}$ is parallel to $\boldsymbol{\omega}$.

The condition that $$ {\rm I}_C\boldsymbol{\omega} = \lambda\, \boldsymbol{\omega} $$ where $\lambda$ is a scalar value, is the eigenvalue problem for ${\rm I}_C$. The 3×3 symmetric matrix ${\rm I}_C$ has three orthogonal directions associated with it where this happens. These are called the three [principal axes of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Principal_axes) of the body.

So the condition is that the rotational velocity vector $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ must be along one of these three principal directions.

Typically a body with a cylindrical symmetry will have the axis of symmetry as principal axis. Also, any axis perpendicular to the symmetry axis would also be principal. For a body with a symmetry plane two of principal axis would be on the plane, and one perpendicular to the plane.

### Part 2

Related to [Chasles' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chasles%27_theorem_(kinematics)#) is the fact that the motion of any particle on a rigid body *can* be decomposed as a transpaltional velocity of that point, plus a rotation about this point. The choice of point is arbitrary, as you can move from one point to another using the transformation law

$$ \boldsymbol{v}_B = \boldsymbol{v}_A + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times ( \boldsymbol{r}_B - \boldsymbol{r}_A) $$

The time derivative of the above results in the acceleration transformation law

$$ \boldsymbol{a}_B = \boldsymbol{a}_A + \boldsymbol{\alpha} \times ( \boldsymbol{r}_B - \boldsymbol{r}_A) + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times ( \boldsymbol{v}_B - \boldsymbol{v}_A)$$

which is exactly the relation you are asking about, just pick **A** as the particle *i* point and **B** the center of mass.